# What's the difference between a double pointer and a function with return while using single-linked lists?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have this declaration:

```
struct node {
      int value;
      struct node * next;
  };
```

Then I would to compare this two functions:

```
struct node* function1(struct node *p) {
       p = p->next;
       return p;
}

void function2(struct node **p) {
    (*p) = (*p)->next;
}
```

In the main function we have respectively:

```
head = funcion1(head);
function2(&head);
```

Someone told me "you have to use double pointer
when you need to update your list's head", but
in both cases I update it.
Can you help me understand the differences?

Comment: The end result of both is the same. Use whichever suits your needs.

Comment: You are not updating the head of the list. You just walk the list. Then a double pointer is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are different. In `function1` the changes made to `struct node* p` is local to the block of `function1` i.e. change is temporary. But In `function2` the changes made to `struct node* p` NOT local to the block of `function2` i.e. it is permanent (until it is changed again).

This is related to concept of `Call-by-value` and `Call-by-reference`. Just to be precise, following points are note-worthy:

- In `Call-by-value`, changes made to parameters are local to function block but in `Call-by-reference`, changes made to parameters are permanent
- To pass a value as `Call-by-value`, we define the parameter of the function as that particular type e.g. if we want to pass `int` to `f1` function then its deceleration will be like `void f1(int val);`. To pass a value as `Call-by-reference`, we define the parameter of the function as that *pointer of particular type* e.g. if we want to pass `int` to `f1` function then its deceleration will be like `void f1(int* val);` and call will be like `int a= 0; f1(&a);`.
- To pass the pointer as reference, the function should have `one-more-level-of-indirection`. e.g. to pass `int *a;` function should be declared as `void f1(int** val);`; to pass `int **a;` function should be declared as `void f1(int*** val);` and so on

Try following code. See [this code working here](https://ideone.com/reMeVK):

```
struct node * p1 = (struct node*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
struct node * p2 = (struct node*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));

p1->next = NULL;
p2->next = NULL;

printf("p1 = %p; and p2 = %p\n", p1, p2);

function1(p1);
function2(&p2);

printf("p1 = %p; and p2 = %p", p1, p2);
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
p1 = 0x5604536cf260; and p2 = 0x5604536cf280
p1 = 0x5604536cf260; and p2 = (nil)
```

In above output you can see that address of `p1` is not updated but address of `p2` is updated.

Answer (score 1):

In the following example you must use a double pointer:

```
int main()
{
    struct node *head= NULL;
    createList (&head);
    //...
}

void createList(struct node **head)
{
    *head= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

In main you declare a list. Function `createList` initializes it with the first node. For the function to be able to do that, it needs to know where the caller wants the new node to be stored. For that it needs the *address* of the caller's variable, i.e. a double pointer.

Comment: Thanks. But if i have `head = createList(head)` and in the function `struct node * tmp = malloc.....; return tmp;` is the same, or not?

Comment: Yes. You  can also use the function return. But...I only give an example to illustrate the mechanism and why&how.

Comment: The key thing to understand about a double pointer is "the _address_ of the caller's variable to place the result in."

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between a double pointer and a function with return while using single-linked lists?

Do you want the function to update `head` or the calling code?
The choice is yours.

---

> Someone told me "you have to use double pointer when you need to update your list's head", but in both cases I update it.

It is more like "you have to use double pointer when you need to *have the function* update your list's head".

```
function2(&head);
```

In the other case, calling code does the update in order to maintain `head` with a proper value.

```
head = funcion1(head);
```

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, using double pointers will allow a function to offer better failure semantics than using a return value.  For example, a function to resize an allocation, which is supposed to leave an allocation unmodified in case of failure, could simply refrain from modifying the outside pointer to the allocation, rather than requiring that the caller keep a copy of the original pointer and then use that instead of the function's return value when the function returns null.

Unfortunately, while the language described in K&R2 would allow a function that accepts a `struct ANYTHING **ref` to use it directly to update a pointer to any kind of structure [since structure pointers can be converted to and from `void*` within compilation units that don't contain definitions for those structures, all pointers to structure types must have the same representation], and while all versions of the C Standard would allow compilers to support such constructs, no versions of the Standard forbid compilers from requiring that programmers jump through hoops to accomplish such things; the authors of clang and gcc treat the lack of prohibition as an invitation.

Consequently, if one wants to use such constructs in a way compatible with the `-fstrict-aliasing` dialect processed by clang and gcc, one must use `memcpy` to update pointers rather than using assignments.  Depending upon the implementation one is using, this may or may not yield code that is as efficient as a simple assignment would be.  If one goes this route,. I'd suggest:

```
#ifdef JUMP_THROUGH_SILLY_HURDLES_FOR_CLANG_AND_GCC
memcpy(origRef, &newPointerValue, sizeof newPointerValue);
#else
*((STRUCT ANYTHING**)origRef) = newPointerValue;
#endif
```

so that one can achieve efficient and correct behavior either when using a quality commercial compiler which would assume one would only use `memcpy` in cases where the source and destination weren't known to both be aligned (and would thus generate slower code for that case on platforms that don't natively handle unaligned accesses), or one is using compilers which require using `memcpy` even in cases where a simple word-aligned load and store would suffice.